# MySQL Query getting always same result

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I'm trying to do some verification for my "clients".
The client insert his ID and then a window alert pop up saying that he/she is registered (and already paid) or not registered.

But, it returns always the "Inscrição feita e paga!" (Inscription and paid!)

```
<?php

include("./config.php");

$BI       = $_POST['BI'];

$query = mysql_query ("SELECT id_atleta from atleta where num_cidadao = '$BI'");

        if ($query)

        {
                    $resultado = mysql_fetch_row($query); 

                    $query2 = "SELECT * FROM inscricao WHERE atleta_id_atleta = '$resultado' AND data_pagamento!= '0000-00-00 00:00:00'";


                        if ($query2)

                                {

                                echo ("<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>
                                window.alert('Inscrição feita e paga!')
                                window.location.href='';
                                </SCRIPT>");

                                }

                                else
                                {

                                    echo ("<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>
                                window.alert('Isncrição a aguardar pagamento!')
                        window.location.href='';
                        </SCRIPT>");

                                }

        }
            else
            {
           echo ("<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>
                           window.alert('Não existe nenhuma inscrição associada a este BI!')
                   window.location.href='';
                   </SCRIPT>");
   }
     ?>
```

Comment: `$query2 = "SELECT ` should probably be `$query2 = mysql_query("SELECT `

Comment: You've got to execute your second query too. But I think, one query with a nice join or subselect would do. There are some security aspects too. You would better move to PDO or mysqli with prepared statements and placeholders and bind your input values to these.

Comment: NEVER EVER take some data from _POST and put it into mysql_query without escaping it properly. THIS IS A HUGE SECURITY RISK!. Check http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php

Comment: You're assigning a string value to $query2 rather than doing an actual query so it will always return TRUE. Also, as the others have mentioned, your script has a multitude of security issues.

Comment: This single query would do: `SELECT * FROM inscricao i INNER JOIN atleta a ON a.id_atleta = i.inscricao WHERE data_pagamento != '0000-00-00 00:00:00' AND a.num_cidadao = '$BI'`. But better rewrite this with a parameterized prepared statement, to avoid sql injection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this code:

```
$query2 = "SELECT * FROM inscricao WHERE atleta_id_atleta = '$resultado' AND data_pagamento!= '0000-00-00 00:00:00'";
if ($query2)
```

You're not executing the query, you're simply checking if $query2 (a string) is not false or null. So of course, you're going to always get whatever comes after `if($query2)`.

Answer (score 0):

Try getting the number of rows:

```
$result = mysql_query($query2, $link);
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

if ($num_rows === 1) {

    echo ("<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>
    window.alert('Inscrição feita e paga!')
    window.location.href='';
   </SCRIPT>");

   }

    else
    {

     echo ("<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>
     window.alert('Isncrição a aguardar pagamento!')
     window.location.href='';
   </SCRIPT>");

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help.
I know that for security reasons this isn't much help but thanks to your help i managed to correct the code

```
<?php

include("./config.php");

$BI       = $_POST['BI'];

$query = mysql_query ("SELECT id_atleta from atleta where num_cidadao = '$BI'");

        if (mysql_num_rows($query))

        {
                    $resultado = mysql_fetch_row($query); 

                    $query2 = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM inscricao WHERE atleta_id_atleta = '$resultado[0]' AND data_pagamento!= '0000-00-00 00:00:00'");


                        if (mysql_num_rows($query2))

                                {

                                echo ("<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>
                                window.alert('Inscrição feita e paga!')
                                window.location.href='';
                                </SCRIPT>");

                                }

                                else
                                {

                                    echo ("<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>
                                window.alert('Isncrição a aguardar pagamento!')
                        window.location.href='';
                        </SCRIPT>");

                                }

        }
            else
            {
           echo ("<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>
                           window.alert('Não existe nenhuma inscrição associada a este BI!')
                   window.location.href='';
                   </SCRIPT>");
   }
     ?>
```